# How to discard the vertical lines when plotting piecewise functions in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot the following piecewise function
[image]

in the range [-3,6].

I use the following instructions

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
x = np.linspace(-3,6,1000)
interval0 = [1 if (i<2) else 0 for i in x]
interval1 = [1 if (i==2) else 0 for i in x]
interval2 = [1 if (i>2 and i<=6) else 0 for i in x]

y = x**2*interval0 + 6*np.ones(1000)*interval1 + (10-x)*interval2

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

I get the following graph
[image]

How can I get rid of the vertical line at x=2 (i.e. the point of discontinuity)?

Comment: Try looking at [this](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/11477/plotting-discontinuous-functions) and see if it helps

Comment: You could use `y[np.argmin(np.abs(x - 2))] = np.nan` to set the y-value to NaN for the x closest to `2`. That will create a gap in the plot of the curve. Note that in general it is very unlikely for an x-value to be exactly equal to some specific number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just plot three segment separately since you have the point `(2,6)` anyway:

```
# the two continuous segments
x1 = np.linspace(-3,2,1000)
x2 = np.linspace(2,6,1000)

# plot
plt.plot(x1, x1**2, color='C0')
plt.scatter(2,6)
plt.plot(x2, 10-x2, color='C0')
```

Output:

[image]